# MySQL query on two tables with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
`users` and `users_img`.

I need to create one query to select all users from `users` table that have `zip` column not empty AND have `img` column empty in `users_images` (both tables have user ids: `users`.`id` and `users_img`.`user_id` so those could be joined).

**`users`**

1. id
2. name
3. zip
4. last_time

**`users_ids`**

1. id
2. user_id (same as `id` in `users`)
3. img

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `users_ids` on users.id = users_ids.user_id
 WHERE `zip` != '' AND `img` = '' ORDER BY `last_time` DESC
```

with no luck. I know is supposed to be quite simple.

Comment: from your logic, it should be at least `..WHERE \`zip\` != '' AND \`img\` = ''`. also are you sure they're blank and not null. post also some sample data

Comment: maybe u should include the schema of ur table?

Comment: @amdixon  - yes, of course, man. but that's not the point. I'll need this query too (when both zip and img are not empty

Comment: not sure how to do that. but I'll add some additional info to make it clearer.Thanks!!

Comment: You are getting any error in you query?

Comment: Code-Monk - no, just ZERO results.
there are about 200 users in `users` table and only three of those have images in 'users_ids')

Comment: you may have `Null` in columns,In that case checking empty sting will not work.so,It will be helpful for us if you add snap shot of data you have in table.

Comment: no no - it's ok... I can check if column are empty separately with no problems. so ='' check works

Comment: You need to produce an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In a question about queries from a database, that usually means you need to show a minimal schema for the tables, a small set of rows for each table, the results you are getting, why that result is wrong, and the desired result.  You probably need 3-6 entries in the `users` table, and slightly fewer rows for the `user_ids` table.  Without that, we're forced to guess what your problems are.

Comment: Jonathan, you are right. 
Despite teh fact I ahev provided all necessary info - it is not good enough replacement of MCVE. I was wondering how to posy MySQL Db structure here? I se ethsoe beautifully made examples but have no clue how to create mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will also work for you

```
SELECT * FROM `users` as `u` 
JOIN `users_ids` as `uid` on `u`.`id` = `uid`.`user_id` 
WHERE `u`.`zip` IS NOT NULL 
AND `uid`.`img` IS NULL 
ORDER BY `u`.`last_time` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your query to check for `Null` values also in `OR`

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `users_ids` on users.id = users_ids.user_id 
WHERE   (TRIM(`zip`) != '' OR `zip` is not null)  AND 
(TRIM(`img`) = '' OR `img` is null) ORDER BY `last_time` DESC
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set
pretty much like with my request
amd `img`    tinytext,  latin1_swedish_ci  , No (about null)

Comment: You may have mismatched values in your joining tables. Please check this also.

Comment: Either of your table may have empty data or the records  which are present not matching with userID's

Comment: Try this query without `where` clause also. If you don't get any results, which means that we are having problem in  `JOIN`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `users` 
JOIN `users_ids` on users.id = users_ids.user_id 
WHERE   (`zip` != '' OR `zip` is not null)  AND 
(`img` != '' OR `img` is not null) ORDER BY `last_time` DESC 

when I make this query - I get three results (as there are three users that have both zip and img not empty). But there are 200 of thsoe who have ZIP not empty but IMG empty and for a strange reason I cannot get those!

Comment: to answer your question  - without WHERE clause it returns also those three results. Maybe it is a bit incorrect approach?

Comment: I just want to verify that value are matching or not

Comment: so they do. appears that the request returns ony matchng results in both tables while I need either all from "USERS' that do have IMG not empty..or those who have IMG empty. in first case - three users, in teh sceond case - 200 users

Comment: I have updated Answer.Please check once again. I have added `Left Join` to search for those users also who are not present in  `users_ids` table

Comment: emm.. not it returns ALL users (even those who have "ZIP" empty)

Comment: You may have leading spaces in your `ZIP` column,that's why filter condition in `where` clause is not working. Try updating it to `WHERE   (TRIM(zip) != '' OR zip is not null)  AND 
(TRIM(img) = '' OR img is null)`. Added Trim to remove leading spaces.

Comment: still it returns all users who have IMG as NULL but at the same time their ZIP in many cases is empty WHERE   (`zip` != '' OR `zip` is not null) notwithstanding...

Comment: Please share data of both tables,so that i can try it on SQL fiddle .

Comment: as `users` table contains personal data I have duplicated it and added several fake profiles for testing purposes. Thak you very much for your time!
http://a5w.org/sql.zip

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` as `u` 
LEFT JOIN `users_ids` as `uid` on `u`.`id` = `uid`.`user_id` 
WHERE `u`.`zip` != '' 
AND `uid`.`img` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY `u`.`last_time` DESC
```